# Results still showing after filtering with parameter passed to the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a parameter that is passed to a action from a view that when matched only shows those corresponding results.

Everything works as normal when the parameter passed in has a match, but when the id being passed it does not match any id, the corresponding view is showing all the results.

```
public ActionResult ShowResults(Guid ParameterId)
        {                
          return this.PartialView(this.MyClassVariable.MyGetMStuffMetod().Where(x => x.Id == ParameterId));
        }
```

Is there a way I can tell it if the ids do not match return nothing?

My Method

```
public IList<MyStuffViewModel> MyGetStuffMethod()
        {

            IList<MyStuffViewModel> result = (IList<MyStuffViewModel>)HttpContext.Current.Session["MyStuff"];

            if (result == null)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session["MyStuff"] = result =
                    (from mStuff in new dbEntities().TableA


                     select new MyStuffViewModel
                     {
                         Id = mStuff.Id,
                         Name = mStuff.Name

                     }).ToList();
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Comment: What's happens if you call .ToList() after the .Where() call?

Comment: return this.PartialView(this.MyClassVariable.MyGetMStuffMetod().Where(x => x.Id == ParameterId).ToList());                                        Does the same and displays all the results as well.

Comment: It looks like you are pulling back everything into memory with the MyGetMStuffMethod() and then trying to filter out based on Id...

Maybe similar to what contactmatt said, try this instead: this.MyClassVariable.MyGetMStuffMetod().ToList().Where(x => x.Id == ParameterId)

Comment: drneel -- I am pulling it back and filtering with the parameter like you said, and that .ToList() is also returning everything.

Comment: Do you have data you can add? Or what kind of Type x.Id and ParameterId are?  For example if the Id is an enum (unlikely) it would default to 0, which might make it appear as if it is returning all results when it's actually working correctly.

Comment: Sure Let me grab it.  The ids are Guids.

Comment: So the correct id is passed to the method then it queries the db and returns all if ParameterId != Id, but if ParameterId == Id, the correct results show.

Comment: This fixed it, but it should work w/out the Grouping, I must have something else going on.  I will let you know if I can trck it down.               .Where(x => x.Id == ParameterId).GroupBy(t => t.ParameterId));

Answer (score 0):

This worked, but I think it is something else causing the issue, I will track it down and post the results.  Thanks for the help.

```
 .Where(x => x.Id == ParameterId).GroupBy(t => t.ParameterId));
```